# kdiff3 сохраняет изменения не в оригинальный файл

Tags: git, git-merge

Никак не могу разобраться, почему **kdiff3** сохраняет изменения не в оригинальный файл. Он создает файл рядом с оригинальным и записывает изменения в него, то есть у меня после мержа каталог выглядит так
[image: каталог]

И все изменения сохраняются во втором сверху файле `a.txt`, а надо в первом, оригинальном.

Можно заметить как **kdiff3** что-то добавляет в название файла

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Конечно это всё происходит после комманды `git mergetool`. Может быть это **git** неправильно передает аргументы в **kdiff3**?

Comment: Судя по скриншоту, вы используете Windows. Откуда брали kdiff3 и какой версии? У меня есть подозрение, что ошибка в нем.

Comment: Честно сказать не знаю, но помогла полная переустановка. Спасибо!